# italic correction in math mode

Tags: math-mode, kerning, letterspacing, italic-correction

I use `txfonts` and `\texttt` in italics in math mode, but the letters' italic correction is not working: an italic/"TT" letter "d" adjacent to a closing parenthesis touches it. Here is minimal sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\newcommand*{\halfthinspace}{\kern .08333em} % not sure whether I got this value right
\newcommand*{\shorthalfthinspace}{\kern .06em}
\newcommand*{\somefunction}[1]{\textit{F}(#1)}
\newcommand*{\ittt}[1]{\textit{\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\(\somefunction{\ittt{pd}}\) (what I get)

\(\somefunction{\ittt{pd}\shorthalfthinspace}\) (I want this)

\(\somefunction{\ittt{pd}\halfthinspace}\) (or this)

This is entity \ittt{pd}. (use of \verb|\ittt| within text; the spacing here is good)

\(\ittt{pd} \times \ittt{pd}\) (the space before the times symbol is minimally too thin)

\end{document}
```

To include additional space in the definition of `\somefunction` (`\newcommand*{\somefunction}[1]{\textit{F}(#1\shorthalfthinspace)}`) seems to be semantically the wrong approach. To include additional space in the definition of `\ittt` seems equally wrong, especially since I would occasionally like to use `\ittt` within text (see line 4 generated by my sample code) and don't want additional spacing before the sentence-final period. Finally, I may use `\ittt` in other contexts, such as around a `\times` operator (see line 5 generated by my sample code); the spacing doesn't only *look* too thin, it *is* too thin (easy to verify by turning the result by 180° in your viewer).

What it the easiest way to get appropriate spacing in all situations?

*Note: I don't know whether this is an italic correction issue or something to do with `\texttt` or the structure of my macros. Feel free to improve the title of my question accordingly.*

Comment: (`tt` stands for typwriter.) Why do use `\textit` in math mode? `F(#1)` would be typeset correct (and in italics) and uses the right spacing between `F` and `(`.

Comment: Just an additional hint: There is the relative new package `newtx`. You should consider to switch over, take at least a closer look on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `\somefunction`

I have remove `\textit` entirely. In math mode variables (a-zA-Zα-ο) are usually typeset in italic shape. Math mode takes care of the italic correction (between `F` and `(` in this case).
If you want to use `\somefunction` in text, use *always* inline math (`\(…\)`).

---

It wouldn't be that wrong to use a simple definition for the entity (`pd`) and “fix” the spacing inside `\somefunction` (or better: `entityFunction`/`\funcOfEnt`/…) *except* when parenthesized entities will be used more often and outside of a function, like `(\entity{pd} + \entity{qr}) x`, than the definition of the function should use the already patched `\entity` to be more consistent.

## `\textit` and `\texttt`

I don't think there is a total automatic solution available for fixing the problem with `)` and following punctuation.

Let's take a look at the options:

### `\ittt`

Your original `\ittt` was defined as

```
\newcommand*{\ittt}[1]{\textit{\texttt{#1}}}
```

#### `\itttm`

If you only use your entities in text mode before punctuation, `\itttm` can work for you. It adds italic correction only in math mode.

```
\newcommand*{\itttm}[1]{%
    \ifmmode\mmodebeforetrue\else\mmodebeforefalse\fi%
    \textit{\texttt{#1\ifmmodebefore\/\fi}}%
}
```

#### `\itttp`

The macro `\itttp` typsets a second optional parameter in italic shape (but not in the typewriter family). [This has been discussed on TeX.SE already.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14983/16595)
In my eyes, this is even too tight.

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\itttp}{m O{}}{%
  \textit{\texttt{#1}#2\/}%
}
```

### `\ttit`

Switching `\textit` and `\texttt` gives us italic correction. But it also adds this italic correction before punctuation mark where you don't want it (i.e., `.` and `,`).

```
\newcommand*{\ttit}[1]{\texttt{\textit{#1}}}
```

#### `\ttitc`

Like `\ttit`, but:
The if-macro `\@ifnextchar` removes the italic correction before `.` and `,` with a negative kern.

### [`\emph` or `\textit`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1980/16595)?

I also tested both variants with `\emph`:

- `\emph{\texttt{pd}}` is a little better before `)`, and as good as `\ittt` before punctuation
- `\texttt{\emph{pd}}` is as bad as `\ttit`.

### `\entity[*]{<arg>}`

I also declared another macro: `\entity`. It does exist in a non-starred and a starred form.
Use the starred form if you do *not* want italic correction (i.e. before `.` and `,`).

### Conclusion

I think the best solutions are:

- `\itttm` if you need italic correction only in math mode.
- `\ttitc` if can handle a few cases where the automatically inserted correction has to be re-corrected
- `\entity` if you're willing to use a switch (the `*`) to toggle italic correction (it should be doable to use `\@ifnextchar` in `\entity`, too).

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{array,multirow,xcolor} %                       for presentation
\def\dont{\color[gray]{.5}} %                              *
\usepackage{xparse}%                                       for \itttp and \entity
\newif\ifmmodebefore%                                      for \itttm

\newcommand*{\somefunction}[1]{F(#1)}

\newcommand*{\ittt}[1]{\textit{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\ttit}[1]{\texttt{\textit{#1}}}

\newcommand*{\itttm}[1]{%                                  \itttc inserts italic correction \/ if in math mode
  \ifmmode\mmodebeforetrue\else\mmodebeforefalse\fi%
  \textit{\texttt{#1\ifmmodebefore\/\fi}}%
}

\makeatletter %                                            needed because @ is used in macro name
\newcommand*{\ttitc}[1]{%                                  \ttitc checks if . or , follows and kerns
  \texttt{\textit{#1}}%
  \@ifnextchar.{\kern-.1em}{\@ifnextchar,{\kern-.08em}{}}%
}
\makeatother

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\itttp}{m O{}}{%                   optional punctuation will be typeset italic
  \textit{\texttt{#1}#2\/}%
}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\entity}{s m}{%                     star = no italic correction (before , and .)
  \textit{\texttt{#2}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {}%
    {\/}%
  }%
}

%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug} % use this with LuaLaTeX for debug-mode
\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l@{}c@{ }c@{ }c}
    macro                &              math               &              \verb|\times|              &               text                \\ \hline&             text mode             \\ \hline
    \verb|\ittt{pd}|     &         $(\ittt{pd} )$          &         $ \ittt{pd} \times {}$          &       \ittt{pd}, \ittt{pd}.       \\ \hline
    \verb|\itttm{pd}|    &         $(\itttm{pd})$          &         $ \itttm{pd} \times {}$         &      \itttm{pd}, \itttm{pd}.      \\
    \verb|\itttp{pd}|    &         $(\itttp{pd})$          &         $ \itttp{pd} \times {}$         &   \dont \itttp{pd}, \itttp{pd}.   \\
    \verb|\itttp{pd}[.]| &               ---               &                   ---                   &    \itttp{pd}[,] \itttp{pd}[.]    \\ \hline
    \verb|\ttit{pd}|     & \multirow{2}{*}{$(\ttit{pd} )$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$ \ttit{pd} \times {}$} &       \ttit{pd}, \ttit{pd}.       \\
    \verb|\ttitc{pd}|    &                                 &                                         &      \ttitc{pd}, \ttitc{pd}.      \\ \hline
    \verb|\entity{pd}|   &         $(\entity{pd})$         &        $ \entity{pd} \times {}$         & \dont   \entity{pd}, \entity{pd}. \\
    \verb|\entity*{pd}|  &               ---               &                   ---                   &    \entity*{pd}, \entity*{pd}.    \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

## Output

[image: Output table]

Comment: 1. I don't quite see an effect of `\@ifnextchar.{\kern-.1em}{\@ifnextchar,{\kern-.08em}{}}`. 2. I like the content of your writing very much (and I understand it I think), but could you expand it a bit with prose?

Comment: @user14996 I've updated (read: overhauled) my answer. Hopefully it is more understandable now. The effect of `\@ifnextchar` is visible  when you compare `\ttit` and `\ttitc`.

Comment: Is there a way to have the correction of `\ttitc` work if the macro is within macro but the following punctuation outside?

Comment: @user14996 So that `{\ttitc{pd}}.` works as `{\ttitc{pd}.}`? I suppose this is doable, but I don't know how, though. Why can't you put the punctuation inside the outer macro? Anyway, I suggest asking a separate question as this isn't related to italic corrections.

Comment: I meant (maybe this is what you have in mind too) that I may write something like `\([...] \ttitc{pd}\).` and would like italic correction to apply nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

If `\texttt` and `\textit` are exchanged, then the italics correction is inserted.
Also in the example, `\textit` is only applied to `F` if not in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\newcommand*{\somefunction}[1]{%
  \ifmmode\else\expandafter\textit\fi F(#1)%
}
\newcommand*{\ittt}[1]{\textit{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\ttit}[1]{\texttt{\textit{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\(\somefunction{\ittt{pd}}\)

\(\somefunction{\ttit{pd}}\)

\(\ittt{pd}a\)

\(\ttit{pd}a\)

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]