# How to get upright parentheses in the whole document?

Tags: fonts, punctuation, typography, italic

My question is, basically, the same as the one in [Upright parentheses in italic text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13048/upright-parentheses-in-italic-text): how do I force all parentheses in my document to be upright, without replacing them with some commands "by hand"?

Unlike the linked question, my main concern are slanted environments (i.e., theorems). At the moment, I'm dealing with `elsarticle`, which uses `\itshape` which is not covered by the solutions on above link (and I don't see how I could modify them to do so), nor by the `embrac` package (explicitly stated in Section 9).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
I want parenthesis (around this text) to be upright.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I can, of course, write

```
I want parenthesis {\rm (}around this text{\rm )} to be upright.
```

or define some commands for the upright parentheses and use them. However, changing the parentheses in the LaTeX code can lead to errors (for example, missing some of them and introducing inconsistency) and puts a burden of focusing on that detail, instead of the text I'm writing, so I'd prefer some automated way (like the one shown for `\emph` in the linked document).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @henrique: I apologize. I thought the question was fairly obvious. I've added it now and I hope it's ok now.

Comment: I'm afraid that the only *really* robust solution is to have italic fonts with upright parentheses. I tend to avoid parentheses in italics contexts or use `\textup(...\textup)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As egreg warned, the following will probably break many things. But it works in simple situations. [code edited following egreg's advice]

[update: at the bottom of this answer I edit the answer to be compatible with `\label` and `\ref`]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\catcode1=12
\catcode2=12
\mathcode1=\the\mathcode`\(
\delcode1=\the\delcode`\(
\mathcode2=\the\mathcode`\)
\delcode2=\the\delcode`\)

\catcode`\(=\active
\catcode`\)=\active

\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\let(^^A\let)^^B}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\let(^^A\let)^^B}

%%\def({\begingroup\upshape\char`\(\endgroup}
%%\def){\begingroup\upshape\char`\)\endgroup}
\def({\textup{\char`\(}}
\def){\textup{\char`\)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
I want parenthesis (around this text) to be upright. Of course, parentheses in
math mode are already upright: $\Bigg((E = mc^2)\Bigg)$, and we don't want to
fiddle with them.
\end{theorem}
\[ \Bigg((E = mc^2)\Bigg) \]
I want parenthesis (around this text) to be upright. 
\emph{I want parenthesis (around this text) to be upright. }
\end{document}
```

[image: upright parenthesis in text mode, math mode unchanged]

with egreg's suggestion the spacing appears to be better:

[image]

Code for (hopefully...) compatibility with `\label` and `\ref` (with or without `hyperref` used in the document):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\def\makeparenletter{\catcode`\(=11 \catcode`\)=11 }
\def\makeparenother{\catcode`\(=12 \catcode`\)=12 }
\def\makeparenactive{\catcode`\(=\active\catcode`\)=\active}

\catcode1=12
\catcode2=12
\mathcode1=\the\mathcode`\(
\delcode1=\the\delcode`\(
\mathcode2=\the\mathcode`\)
\delcode2=\the\delcode`\)

\makeparenactive
\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\let(^^A\let)^^B}
\everydisplay\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\let(^^A\let)^^B}
\def({\textup{\char`\(}}
\def){\textup{\char`\)}}
\makeparenother

\AtBeginDocument{% this is at begin document as it must be done
                 % after hyperref does its things
\makeparenactive
\let\zzzlabel\label
\let\zzzref\ref
\let\zzznewlabel\newlabel

\def\label{\makeparenletter\wwwlabel}
\def\ref{\makeparenletter\wwwref}
\def\newlabel{\makeparenletter\wwwnewlabel}

\def\wwwlabel#1{\makeparenactive\zzzlabel{#1}}
\def\wwwref#1{\makeparenactive\zzzref{#1}}
\def\wwwnewlabel#1{\makeparenactive\zzznewlabel{#1}}}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{theorem}\label{(thm:1)}
I want parenthesis (around this text) to be upright. Of course, parentheses in
math mode are already upright: $\Bigg((E = mc^2)\Bigg)$, and we don't want to
fiddle with them.
\end{theorem}
\[ \Bigg((E = mc^2)\Bigg) \]
I want parenthesis (around this text) to be upright. 
\emph{I want parenthesis (around this text) to be upright. \textbf{I want parenthesis (around this text) to be upright. }}

Theorem \ref{(thm:1)}
\end{document}
```

[image: with label and ref added]

Comment: Try ``\def){\textup{\char`\)}}`` and you'll see an improvement.

Comment: @egreg thanks, modified the code. The spacing appears to be better, why is that? (I have to leave now)

Comment: Thank you both, this seems to do a great job! For anyone else reading this, one of the things that breaks are labels and references with parentheses in them. These are, of course, easily edited if one knows what to looks for.

Comment: @jfbu `\textup` has heuristics for deciding whether to add an italic correction, which `\upshape` hasn't.

Comment: @egreg ok, didn't know that.

Comment: I'm using `\\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]` and find your code is not compatible with these parentheses in enumerate environment. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `pre_linebreak_filter` of LuaTeX.  This also allows you to insert a little kerning around the parentheses.  The solution below only works for `\normalsize` but can easily be generalized, also to different fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
local open = 1
local close = 2

local match = {
    [utf.byte("(")] = open,
    [utf.byte(")")] = close,
    [utf.byte("[")] = open,
    [utf.byte("]")] = close,
}

fontmap = {}

local upright_parens = function(head)
    for glyph in node.traverse_id(node.id("glyph"), head) do
        if match[glyph.char] then
            local replaced = false
            if glyph.font == fontmap.it then
                glyph.font = fontmap.tf
                replaced = true
            elseif glyph.font == fontmap.bfit then
                glyph.font = fontmap.bf
                replaced = true
            end
            if replaced and match[glyph.char] == open then
                local kern = node.new("kern")
                kern.kern = -.2 * glyph.width
                node.insert_after(head, glyph, node.copy(kern))
            end
            if replaced and match[glyph.char] == close then
                local kern = node.new("kern")
                kern.kern = .2 * glyph.width
                node.insert_before(head, glyph, node.copy(kern))
            end
        end
    end
    return head
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter", upright_parens, "upright parens")
```

```
\end{luacode*}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \textup{\directlua{fontmap.tf = font.current()}}
  \textit{\directlua{fontmap.it = font.current()}}
  \textbf{\directlua{fontmap.bf = font.current()}}
  \textit{\textbf{\directlua{fontmap.bfit = font.current()}}}
}

\begin{document}\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{theorem}\label{(thm:1)}
  I want parenthesis (around this text) to be upright. Of course,
  parentheses in math mode are already upright:
  $\Bigg((E = mc^2)\Bigg)$, and we don't want to fiddle with them.
\end{theorem}
\[ \Bigg((E = mc^2)\Bigg) \] I want parenthesis (around this text) to
be upright.  \emph{I want parenthesis (around this text) to be
  upright. \textbf{I want parenthesis (around this text) to be
    upright. }}

Theorem \ref{(thm:1)}
\end{document}
```

[image]