# always upright parenthesises and brackets

Tags: typography, italic

I was suggested by my thesis referee that parenthesizes `()` and citation brackets `[]` (I only use square brackets generated by `biblatex`)should always be in upright.

This is indeed the same question as [Upright parentheses in italic text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13048/) and [How to get upright parentheses in the whole document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86112/).

But the solution ([embrac](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/embrac)) there is not fully satisfactory. First, it produces errors for `\emph{\(math\) not work!}`; second, it does not work for italic texts in `theorem` environment.

Since this is a style problem, I hope that there is no need to modify the code of the main file manually.

Comment: [`embrac`](http://ctan.org/pkg/embrac) does not affect brackets in math mode (since v0.5, according to the documentation). As per egreg's comment to [How to get upright parentheses in the whole document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86112/5872), there probably isn't a perfect solution to that. However, [jfbu's answer to that question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86137/5872) does try to achieve it.

Comment: Parentheses, brackets and braces in math are by default upright, so I find the need for `\emph` in that context puzzling.

Answer (score 4):

What about this:

```
\def\adef#1{\catcode`#1=13 \bgroup \lccode`\~=`#1\lowercase{\egroup\def~}}
\let\emphOri=\emph
\def\emph{\bgroup\adef({\ifmmode(\else{\rm(}\fi}\adef){\ifmmode)\else{\/\rm)}\fi}\emphA}
\def\emphA#1{\emphOri{#1}\egroup}

\emph{text (text) $\bigl( f(x) + y\bigr)$ text}
```

If you need to redefine `\ithsape` too, add the lines:

```
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\addto\itshape{\adef({\ifmmode(\else{\rm(}\fi}\adef){\ifmmode)\else{\/\rm)}\fi}}

{\itshape text (text) $\bigl( f(x) + y\bigr)$ text}
```

I mean that this code is more compact and more readable than `embrac.sty`.

Edit: If you need to give the same behaviour to another braces [square baces, for example], you can try this:

```
\def\adef#1{\catcode`#1=13 \bgroup \lccode`\~=`#1\lowercase{\egroup\def~}}
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\activebraces#1#2{\adef#1{\ifmmode#1\else{\rm#1}\fi}\adef#2{\ifmmode#2\else{\/\rm#2}\fi}}
\let\emphOri=\emph
\def\emph{\bgroup\activebraces()\activebraces[]\emphA}
\def\emphA#1{\emphOri{#1}\egroup}
\addto\itshape{\activebraces()\activebraces[]}
```

But I warn: this will not probably work with automatically generated braces (aka from biblatex) because these braces are already tokenized in the macro. I didn't try it but I assume this behavior. You need to find the braces in the package and replace them by `\rm` version or use some package option (for setting the type of braces). I don't know, sorry, I am not LaTeX specialist.

Comment: This doesn't work for `\itshape` since it relies on the usage of `\emph`.

Comment: @Werner OK, I've added two next lines for `\itshape`. But this was not required by the question.

Comment: The question states: "second, it does not work for italic texts in theorem environment." I assumed this references some form of `\itshape`.

Comment: It seems nice! Could you modify your code that handles square brackets as well? I only use square brackets generated by `biblatex`.

Comment: @MaMing You can try to set `\def\bibleftbracket{{\rm[}}` `\def\bibrightbracket{{\rm]}}`. This is a result from my little reverse engineering of biblatex. This is not mentioned in 300 pages manual. And this is without warranty because I didn't try it with real data because I never use such unnecessarily complicated macro packages.

Comment: @MaMing Would you tell me if the idea from my previous comment works with `biblatex`?

Comment: @wipet I am using `\renewcommand{\mkbibbrackets}[1]{\textup{[}#1\textup{]}}` to manipulate the square brackets.

Comment: @wipet It tested for simple cases, it does work too.

Answer (score 2):

Since v0.8 `embrac` provides `\embparen` for cases like theorem-like environments. The error from the question with math mode cannot be reproduced…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{embrac}[2019-10-01] % v0.8
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\emph{$(x^2)$ not work!}% no error here

\begin{theorem}
  Text \embparen{text} text
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [] brackets in citations can be fixed using the `cite` package:

```
\usepackage{cite}

\def\citeleft{\begingroup\rm[}
\def\citeright{]\endgroup}
```

This doesn't help with the remaining brackets ()'s in the document. FWIW, I always put mine in math mode.

Comment: hello, could you modify your codes to handle `biblatex`? It seems that `biblatex` and `cite` are incompatible.

Comment: Sorry Ma, I don't have any experience with `biblatex`.