# Are Computer Modern italics inconsistent?

Tags: italic, computer-modern

I find the italics of Computer Modern inconsistent: The lower case *o* is too slanted, and the parentheses are too slanted and are too long, resulting in too much air below/above the text, respectively.

I understand that this is a subjective issue and an inexact science, but I find it quite disturbing and was wondering if this is just me or if it's a known issue. And if it's a known issue, is there a cure, other than using an entirely different font?

Here is an attempt to illustrate my point:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\textit{Inconsistent (italics)}
\end{document}
```

[image: Italics example]
[image: Italics example with superimposed lines]

(The issue with the *o* isn't that clear in the picture, perhaps it's easier to see in a denser, less zoomed text.)

Comment: If you don't like the design of a font, use another one. In the famous [“Birth of Venus”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Birth_of_Venus) painting by Botticelli, Venus's left arm is “inconsistent”; would you try and fix it? I'm not saying that Computer Modern italic is as beautiful as that painting, but it reflects its designer’s ideas.

Comment: Here's what [Ralph Waldo Emerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Waldo_Emerson) (1802-1883) had to say about consistency: "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds, adored by little statesmen and philosophers and divines." Is the slant of some of the glyphs really "quite disrturbing"?

Comment: BTW Computer Modern Italic's `o()` are slanted at exactly the same angle as most other characters (the `i` and half of the `n` are a different story), what you are seeing e.g. for `)` is mostly that the curve of the `)` combined with the small character in front of it makes the slant more prominent than in other locations.

Comment: You might be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86112/how-to-get-upright-parentheses-in-the-whole-document . While upright parentheses are objectively less consistent, they often look better subjectively. But as mentioned there, the best approach if you don't like the slant is to use another font.

Comment: Unfortunately, using a different font is not an alternative, since most publishers in my field of mathematics use Computer Modern. I don't really buy the argument that _o_ and _()_ are slanted at the same angle as other characters – when designing a font you can follow a formula to get a rough idea of how characters should look, but small changes for a consistent overall look are essential. And I'll just ignore the condescending remarks about consistency; the job of a typographer is to end up with a uniform, consistent and easy to read page.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the tip about upright parentheses. As a side note, the Times font in e.g. `mathptmx` or `mtpro2` features nice 'o's and smaller, better looking parentheses. I can't force publishers to use them, though.

Comment: @Ulrik - Umm, did you mean to direct your comment at Marcel Krüger?

Comment: Sorry! I meant @MarcelKrüger :)