# citation square brackets upright in theorems

Tags: theorems, italic

How to set up the citation square brackets and numbers in upright in theorems while keeping other stuffs slanted? (This style is suggest by my professor.)

The usual appearance is the following

> *Theorem. There is no biggest prime number (see [1, Theorem 30 at page 100]).*

I would like to achieve

> *Theorem. There is no biggest prime number* (*see* [1, *Theorem* 30 *at page* 100]).

I could manually set `\textup` to numbers to upright but can not set the square brackets to upright.

Comment: Do you use a citation management package such as `cite` or `natbib`? Would you be OK with putting all material, rather than just the numbers, inside the square brackets in upright font?

Comment: I am using biblatex.

Comment: am i correct in assuming that the brackets are provided by your use of `\cite`, and that's why you can't change them?  (certainly, `\textup` applied directly to brackets works as expected.)

Comment: This is related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13048/, but the answer there seems not work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\emph` appears to be your friend.

> [image: upright cite]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}

\newtheorem*{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
There is no biggest prime number \emph{(\cite[Theorem 30 at page 100]{A})}.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
There is no biggest prime number \emph{(\cite[\emph{Theorem} 30 \emph{at page} 100]{A})}.
\end{thm}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{A} author, title

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Now I found that this solution is unrealistic as my file is quite long. It is bitter to change a style afterwards. I also tried http://www.ctan.org/pkg/embrac, it seems not work.

Answer (score 1):

here is a possible solution that also forcibly causes the cited item number to use
`\textup`, so it will not be entirely appropriate if non-numeric labels are used
for the bibliography.

it redefines several commands from `latex.ltx`.  it could be more compactly expressed
using a "patch" mechanism, but i'm not so adept at that technique yet.

the third "theorem" uses the redefined mechanism.

[image: output of example code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}

\newtheorem*{thm}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\thmcite{%
  \@ifnextchar [{\@tempswatrue\@thmcitex}{\@tempswafalse\@thmcitex[]}}
\def\@thmcitex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@thmcite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
\def\@thmcite#1#2{\textup{[}{\textup{#1}\if@tempswa , #2\fi}\textup{]}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
There is no biggest prime number \textup{(}see \textup{[1,}
Theorem \textup{30} at page \textup{100]}.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
There is no biggest prime number (see [1,
Theorem 30 at page 100].
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
There is no biggest prime number \textup{(}see
\thmcite[Theorem \textup{30} at page \textup{100}]{A}.
\end{thm}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{A}
author, title

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```