# Embrac not working within environments

Tags: fonts, typography, italic, embrac

I used the package `embrac` that the following question [Upright parentheses in italic text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13048/upright-parentheses-in-italic-text) let to.

However, If I define a simple environment, it will not work. See the example below. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{embrac}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\TextA}{(\ldots) this is a citation from a famous author}
\newcommand*{\TextB}{\textup{(\ldots)} this is a citation from a famous author}

\textit{\TextA}\\
\textit{\TextB}\\
\TextA

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\expandafter\textit\expandafter{\TextA}`. `embrac` doesn't make `\textit` expand its argument

Comment: BTW: `\newcommand` doesn't define an `environment`. That would be `\newenvironment`.

Comment: Yes. You are right. It was a misspelling from my side. I just wanted a command to illustrate the behaviour.

Comment: @clemens is it difficult/break something if internally you make `embrac` expand `textit` or `emph`?

Comment: Quite easy, actually. In an expl3 programming catcode regime: `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \embrac_textit:nn {no}` (same for `\emph` and `\textsl`)

Comment: I tried to change it using my MWE using your advices, but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: One way around this would be to define `\def\mytextit#1{\expandafter\textit\expandafter{#1}}` and then use `\mytextit{\TextA}`. In my tests this worked.

Comment: Since this doesn't tell me what exactly you've done and what your expectations were I can't really comment on that…

Comment: I have add: `\ExplSyntaxOn
 \cs_generate_variant:Nn \embrac_textit:nn {no}
 \cs_generate_variant:Nn \embrac_emph:nn {no}
 \cs_generate_variant:Nn \embrac_textsl:nn {no}
\ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: @cacamailg It doesn't suffice because the definition of `\textit` still uses the `nn`-variant. You must redefine `\textit`, too, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to expand `\TextA` before feeding it to `\textit`:

```
\expandafter\textit\expandafter{\TextA}
```

If you like you can redefine `\textit` in such a way that it expands its argument one time first:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \embrac_textit:nn {no}

\RenewDocumentCommand \textit {sm}
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      { \embrac_textit:no {*} {#2} }% using the new variant
      { \embrac_textit:no { } {#2} }% using the new variant
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

(Correspondingly with `\embrac_emph:nn` for `\emph` and `\embrac_textsl:nn` for `\textsl`)

Note that this only expands the argument once. In `\textit{x\TextA}` `\TextA` still won't be expanded. You'd need an `x`-variant then (`\edef`-like expansion) but that might be dangerous… Maybe some `\etextit` for usage on own risk:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \embrac_textit:nn {nx}

\NewDocumentCommand \etextit {sm}
  {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1}
      { \embrac_textit:nx {*} {#2} }
      { \embrac_textit:nx { } {#2} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: This actually works. Maybe you can add it to your package as an option like `expandfirst` and also the second variant, with an alert to users.

Comment: Strangely it works with the mininal example, but it is not working with the full document that I am working on. Any ideas?

Comment: @cacamailg No? I don't know your document and not your use case

Comment: The preamble is to big to add it here. I will try to investigate what is happening. Thanks