# Ensuring non-italicization of a character

Tags: fonts, characters

I would like square brackets to never be italicized, even in a `\textit` environment.  That is, I would like to type `[` but have it always replaced with `\textup{[}`, and similarly for the right bracket. Apparently `\newunicodechar` doesn't work for the standard ASCII characters.

Is there some other way?

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13048/35864

Comment: Will the square brackets only ever occur in text mode? Or will some of them occur in math mode? Please advise.

Comment: It’d be pretty straightforward to support `\textit{\bracket{foo} bar}`, but are you looking to make `[` and `]` active characters and not have the other versions available at all?

Comment: Short answer: you can't, unless you're sure to avoid to use *any* optional argument to your commands.

Comment: @Mico — yes, I would only use them in text mode.  Does that help?

Comment: @Davislor2 — I'd be fine making them active characters, and never having an italic square bracket.

Comment: @egreg — Indeed, that's the problem I seem to face.  I hoped there was a solution I had not discovered.

Answer (score 1):

@Moewe's comment above led to the package https://ctan.org/pkg/embrac, which does exactly this. Thank you!